# How to add a standard normal pdf over a seaborn histogram

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram, distribution

I would like to add a standard normal pdf curve over a histogram built with `seaborn`.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns 
x = np.random.standard_normal(1000)
sns.distplot(x, kde = False)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- [`scipy.stats.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/stats.html) gives easy access to the pdf of a normal distribution with
  known parameters; by default it corresponds to the standard normal, `mu=0`, `sigma=1`.

  - This answer works regardless of where the data mean is located (e.g. `mu=0` or `mu=10`)
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `matplotlib 3.4.2`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**
- This question and answer are for axes-level plots; for figure-level plots, see [How to draw a normal curve on seaborn displot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69059121/7758804)

### Imports and Data

```py
import numpy as np                                                              
import seaborn as sns                                                           
from scipy import stats                                                         
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

# data
np.random.seed(365)
x = np.random.standard_normal(1000)
```

### [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html)

```py
ax = sns.histplot(x, kde=False, stat='density', label='samples')

# calculate the pdf
x0, x1 = ax.get_xlim()  # extract the endpoints for the x-axis
x_pdf = np.linspace(x0, x1, 100)
y_pdf = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x_pdf)

ax.plot(x_pdf, y_pdf, 'r', lw=2, label='pdf')                                                   
ax.legend()
```

[image]

### [`seaborn.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) - deprecated

- For this to correspond correctly to your sampled data, the histogram should
  display densities and not counts, so use `norm_hist=True` in the [`seaborn.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) call.

```py
ax = sns.distplot(x, kde = False, norm_hist=True, hist_kws={'ec': 'k'}, label='samples')

# calculate the pdf
x0, x1 = ax.get_xlim()  # extract the endpoints for the x-axis
x_pdf = np.linspace(x0, x1, 100)
y_pdf = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x_pdf)

ax.plot(x_pdf, y_pdf, 'r', lw=2, label='pdf')                                                     
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Why does your plot only go from 0.0 to 0.4?

How do I draw a normal distribution if if have a y-axis with a density that goes from 0 to 8?

Comment: @Jiren **density**: normalize such that the total area of the histogram equals 1. You probably want this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64621456/7758804)