# How to draw a normal curve on seaborn displot

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram, distribution, displot

distplot was deprecated in favour of displot.

The previous function had the option to draw a normal curve.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

ax = sns.distplot(df.extracted, bins=40, kde=False, fit=stats.norm)
```

the `fit=stats.norm` doesn't work with displot anymore. In the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908925/add-a-standard-normal-pdf-over-a-seaborn-histogram), I see the approach to plot the normal later, however it is done on some random data averaged around 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) is a **figure-level** plot where the `kind` parameter specifies the approach. When `kind='hist'` the parameters for   [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) are available.

  - For **axes-level** plots see [How to add a standard normal pdf over a seaborn histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52908925/7758804)
- `seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid.map` expects dataframe column names, as such, to map the pdf onto [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html), the data needs to be in a dataframe.
- An issue is that `x_pdf` is calculated for each `axes`:

  - `x0, x1 = p1.axes[0][0].get_xlim()`
  - If the `axes` are different for multiple Facets (`sharex=False`), then there's not a way to get `xlim` for each `axes` within `.map`.
- References:

  - [seaborn histplot and displot output doesn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68865538/7758804)
  - [Building structured multi-plot grids](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html)
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.2`, `matplotlib 3.4.2`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### Single Facet

- `.map` can be used

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import scipy

# data
np.random.seed(365)
x1 = np.random.normal(10, 3.4, size=1000)  # mean of 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': x1})

# display(df.head(3))
          x1
0  10.570932
1  11.779918
2  12.779077

# function for mapping the pdf
def map_pdf(x, **kwargs):
    mu, std = scipy.stats.norm.fit(x)
    x0, x1 = p1.axes[0][0].get_xlim()  # axes for p1 is required to determine x_pdf
    x_pdf = np.linspace(x0, x1, 100)
    y_pdf = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x_pdf, mu, std)
    plt.plot(x_pdf, y_pdf, c='r')


p1 = sns.displot(data=df, x='x1', kind='hist', bins=40, stat='density')
p1.map(map_pdf, 'x1')
```

[image]

### Single or Multiple Facets

- It's easier to iterate through each axes and add the pdf

```py
# data
np.random.seed(365)
x1 = np.random.normal(10, 3.4, size=1000)  # mean of 10
x2 = np.random.standard_normal(1000)  # mean of 0
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': x1, 'x2': x2}).melt()  # create long dataframe

# display(df.head(3))
  variable      value
0       x1  10.570932
1       x1  11.779918
2       x1  12.779077

p1 = sns.displot(data=df, x='value', col='variable', kind='hist', bins=40, stat='density', common_bins=False,
                 common_norm=False, facet_kws={'sharey': True, 'sharex': False})

# extract and flatten the axes from the figure
axes = p1.axes.ravel()

# iterate through each axes
for ax in axes:
    # extract the variable name
    var = ax.get_title().split(' = ')[1]
    
    # select the data for the variable
    data = df[df.variable.eq(var)]
    
    mu, std = scipy.stats.norm.fit(data['value'])
    x0, x1 = ax.get_xlim()
    x_pdf = np.linspace(x0, x1, 100)
    y_pdf = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x_pdf, mu, std)
    ax.plot(x_pdf, y_pdf, c='r')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replicate the same plot as your `distplot`, I suggest using [`histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html). Fitting our data to a normal is one line of code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.normal(10, 3.4, size=1000)

ax = sns.histplot(x, bins=40, stat='density')

mu, std = stats.norm.fit(x)
xx = np.linspace(*ax.get_xlim(),100)
ax.plot(xx, stats.norm.pdf(xx, mu, std));
```

Output

[image: Histrgram with fitted gaussian]